# Shifting month/day automatically when constructing LocalDate

Tags: java, java-8

This code

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 31);
```

Throws this error:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'APRIL 31'
```

What I need is to construct  a date based on a given number of days, 31 in this case, but since April only has 30 days I get the exception. In the example above, I should get May 1, is this feasible to do with the `java.time` library or needs to be coded manually?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you added days to a base date, right?
Like `LocalDate.of(2019,4,1).plusDays(31);`

Comment: Yes, that will work, thanks for the idea

Comment: but be aware that this is given May 2nd

Comment: Yes, I know, you need to subtract 1 from the number of days

Comment: @OleV.V. Good idea, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, It would probably be easier if you added days to a base date, like this:

```
LocalDate.of(2019,4,1).plusDays(31);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do that, you can try this instead of plusDay:

```
LocalDate.parse("2018-04-31", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT))
```

Comment: It does give `2018-05-01` as requested. Since the asker is coming from three integers rather than a string, it doesn’t seem very rlevant in this case.